# Vertical Menue diffrent width but same CSS code at Submenue

Tags: html, css

I want to write a vertical menu bar with submenues on the right site.
It works for the first sub but the second one is even thiner then the first.
obviously they have the same code but they even seem to be diffrent.

Here the HTML

```
<div class="left_col">
    <div class="menue_left">
        <div class="menu">
        <ul class="ja">
            <li class="ja" id="Willkommen"><a href="'.WB_URL.'/index.php">Willkommen</a></li>
            <li class="ja SuI" id="SuI"><a href="'.WB_URL.'/Historisches/">Service &amp; Info</a>
                <ul class="ja">
                    <li class="ja" id="Historisches"><a href="'.WB_URL.'/Historisches">Historisches</a></li>
                    <li class="ja" id="Oeffnungszeiten"><a href="'.WB_URL.'/Oeffnungszeiten">&Ouml;ffnungszeiten</a></li>
                    <li class="ja" id="Angebot"><a href="'.WB_URL.'/Angebot">Angebot</a></li>
                    <li class="ja" id="Benutzerordnung"><a href="'.WB_URL.'/Benutzerordnung">Benutzerordnung</a></li>
                    <li class="ja" id="Kontakt"><a href="'.WB_URL.'/Kontakt">Kontakt</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="ja MuK" id="Medien"><a href="'.WB_URL.'/Online-Katalog">Medien &amp; Konto</a>
                <ul class="ja">
                    <li class="ja" id="Online-Katalog"><a href="'.WB_URL.'/Online-Katalog">Online-Katalog</a></li>
                    <li class="ja" id="eBook-Ausleihe"><a href="'.WB_URL.'/eBook-Ausleihe">eBook-Ausleihe</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="ja" id="Impressum"><a href="'.WB_URL.'/Impressum">Impressum</a></li>
        </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and here the CSS:

```
.left_col {
position: relative;
margin: 0;
margin-top: 50px;
width: 242px;
height: 820px;
background: yellow;
}

.menue_left {
position: relative;
width:198px;
height: 195px;
top: 50px;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
background: black;
}

.menu {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
position: absolute;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
width: 100%;
}

.menu ul {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
line-height: 40px;
padding: 0;
}

.menu li {
position: relative;
margin: 0;
margin-right: auto;
margin-left: auto;
margin-top: 5px;
padding: 0;
list-style: none;
width: 186px;
width: 200px;
background: #C40012;
z-index: 100;
}

.menu ul li a {
text-align: center;
font-family: "Share", "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
font-weight: bold;
font-size: 16px;
height: 40px;
text-transform: uppercase;
text-decoration: none;
display: block;
color: white;
border: 1px solid white;
z-index: 100;
}

.menu ul ul li a {
border: 1px solid white;
background: #C40012;
z-index: 100;
}

.menu ul li a.ja {
text-decoration: none;
}

.menu ul ul li {
margin-top: 0;
width: 100%;
z-index: 100;
}

.menu ul ul {
position: absolute;
visibility: hidden;
top: 0px;
left: 100%;
z-index: 100;
}

.menu ul li:hover ul {
visibility: visible;
z-index: 100;
}

.menu li:hover {
z-index: 100;
}

.menu a:hover {
color: #333333;
z-index: 100;
}
```

I'm looking forward to hearing from You.

Kind Regards

Ascawath

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add this CSS:

```
.menu ul ul{
    width:100%
}
```

[Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Shady_Alset/hfoxyjq9/)

Comment: @ascawath you're welcome my friend :) you can mark answer as accepted if he was helped you :)